# Can we use a class as method

Tags: kotlin, libgdx

I am analizing a game project.The project's main class has an initialize method.
The project uses a class with constructor like method.
What is this approach name?What is its logic?

For example

This is main class

```
class LevelScreen : BaseScreen(){
override fun initialize() {
        Parallax(0f, 0f, mainStage, "assets/mountains0.png", 35f)
        Parallax(800f, 0f, mainStage, "assets/mountains1.png", 45f)}
}
```

This is called class Parallax

```
class Parallax(x: Float, y: Float, s: Stage, texture: String, speed: Float): BaseActor(x, y, s) {


    init {
        loadTexture(texture)
        setSpeed(speed)
        setMotionAngle(180f)
    }

    override fun act(dt: Float) {
        super.act(dt)
        applyPhysics(dt)

        // if moved completely past left edge of the screen
        // shift right, past other instance
        if (x + width < 0)
            moveBy(2 * width, 0f)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking why a class would have a method called `initialize`? Where did you find this project to analyze? In my opinion, it's poor organization in LibGDX to have various instances of classes instantiating Textures. Textures have to be disposed of to avoid leaking memory, and you don't want to accidentally load multiple copies of the same image. It would be much better to use an AssetManager and pass Texture references around for other classes to borrow.

Comment: Also, the Parallax instances created are not referenced everywhere, so they're wasted and your textures are leaking.

Answer (score 2):

I can't yet post comments, so consider this expanding on @Bruno's answer.

It sounds like your confusion is with the `Parallax` class. In Kotlin, primary constructors are apart of the class header. So `class Parallax(x: Float, y: Float, s: Stage, texture: String, speed: Float): BaseActor(x, y, s)` in Kotlin would be equivalent to the following in Java:

```java
class Parallax extends BaseActor {
    Parallax(float x, float y, Stage s, String texture, float speed){
        super(x, y, s);
    }
}
```

So when Parallax is called twice in `initialize` from `LevelScreen`, that is actually calling the constructor twice (and thus making 2 new objects).

Read more about constructors in Kotlin here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors

Answer (score 1):

The project is not using a class as a function. In fact, it is instantiating two objects without saving them anywhere. For each object the code of the init{} block will be executed